# Scope of a string being assigned in an if statement

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Coming from VB, this just seems weird to me, so I am sure there is a better way to do this...

```
string pulledUserName = ""; // To allow the pulledUserName to be usable in the var result line below ? Really?  If's have their own scope in C#?

            if (await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email) == null)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    pulledUserName = user.UserName;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                 pulledUserName = user.UserName;
            }


            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(pulledUserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

My first go around I assigned the pulledUserName in the IF statement with string pulledUserName = yadda yadda... and it gave me a squiggle saying that it was not in the right scope, so if I "Dim" (yes I know, VB term in a C# question) it above the if statement, it works fine.  So two part question, 
1: Is this really how this works or am I missing something here?
2: This seems clunky to me is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Since you are doing the same thing 3 times and I wouldn't expect the input or output to change at all, I would create a variable outside the `if` block that held the result. You can then check if `user == null` in the 'if' statement, although I would suggest a cleaner `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))` instead of `== null`, since an empty string isn't really null.

Comment: The behavior the variable's scope here is in no way different from VB.NET.  You can't use a variable outside of its scope in either language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I'd refactor into something a little neater...

```
var username = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email) ??
               await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);

var pulledUserName = username?.UserName;
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(pulledUserName,
                                                     model.Password, 
                                                     model.RememberMe, 
                                                     shouldLockout: false);
```

The `??` operator is called the [null coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and will return the first value if it is not null, otherwise it will return the right value. `?.` is called a [null-conditional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) which returns null if `username` is null, otherwise will return the `username.UserName` value.

It may be important to check if `pulledUserName` is null before trying to pass it into the sign-in manager, but thats simple enough.

To directly answer your question though, scope works the same way in c# as it does in VB. You can't use a variable defined outside the current scope,  so yes this is how it works. The way around it is to structure your code such that you avoid creating unnecessary scopes. In C#, { and }, even in the context of an if statement, defines a new scope.

Comment: Was just about to provide this same answer. The null conditional is a nice touch at the end as there's no guarantee that the the UserManager finds a user by either name or e-mail. This is probably more advanced than necessary for the OP. The direct answer is that, yes, you must declare your variables to the appropriate scope. This is no different in VB.

Comment: Thanks,  I'll address that,  I skipped over that part looking at the other issues.